# PHP array sorted into HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have implemented in my game an online score system *via* FTP. Here, take a look at the text file that gets updated :

```
User0:1000
User1:1500
User2:250
User3:700
```

Then, what I'd do is creating a table that has 3 columns :
**Rank | Name | Score**

I was already able to extract the name and the score for each individual line :

```
<table><td>Rank</td><td>Name</td><td>Score</td>
<?php $lines = file("./scores/pk.txt");
for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++) {
    echo "<tr><td></td>";
        echo "<td>".substr($lines[$i],0,strpos($lines[$i],":"))."</td>";
        echo "<td>".substr($lines[$i],strpos($lines[$i],":")+1)."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
} ?> </table<
```

But you know, if I execute this, I get the first column empty (because of the "<td></td>").

So my question is (finally) :

> How to sort this array by third column **and** assigning the right rank in the first column ?

In my example it would look like :

Rank | Name  | Score

1     | User1 | 1500

2     | User0 | 1000

3     | User3 | 700

4     | User2 | 250

Comment: instead of `<td></td>` always use `<td>&nbsp;</td>` the non-breaking space will make the cell actually show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through each line of your file with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it by a colon.

Then you can simply sort it with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). And then you can display the data in your table.

```
<?php

    $lines = file("./scores/pk.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $lines = array_map(function($v){
        return explode(":", $v);
    }, $lines);

    usort($lines, function($a, $b){
        return $b[1] - $a[1];
    });

    echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>Rank</td><td>Name</td><td>Score</td></tr>";
        foreach($lines as $rank => $line)
            echo "<tr><td>" . ($rank+1) . "</td><td>" . $line[0] . "</td><td>" . $line[1] . "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

output:

```
Rank    Name    Score
 1     User1    1500
 2     User0    1000
 3     User3    700
 4     User2    250
```